# Passing data to html web resource via code, crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've put an html web resource on my contract form and would like to pass via the data= parameter some information that comes from a plugin that is registered for PostRetrieve. I know how to set static info for the web resource, but I can't find in the SDK how to set it dynamically from a plugin. Is this possible?

**Background info**
I'm new to developing for CRM so it's quite possible that I'm not taking the most effective route in building this project. Let me give you some more detail: when a contract is opened in CRM, my plugin retrieves some business information from a different sql server and fills in a few of the contract fields. This is working fine. However, I would also like to display a table of usernames and links that come from the remote sql server on the crm contract form. Because I did not want to save this info in the contract entity and because there are links I want the user to click on, I thought a web resource displayed on the form was the best implementation.

My thought was to pass all the data to the web resource via the data= parameter and then parse and build a table using javascript in the web resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What seemed to work best:
The plugin retrieves the info from the remote sql server, serializes the generic list to json and puts it in a hidden text field on the form.

The html web resource gets the content of the hidden field, does an eval, and builds a table.

Comment: how is the html we resource getting the content of the hidden field? Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25140293/1133338